# Bootstrap-select dropdowns not appearing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap-select to prettify my Angular dropdowns. Unfortunately, the options are not rendering when I click on the dropdown.

My master page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ibosApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>iBOS</title>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular/scripts/route-config.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/acs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <ng-view/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my template page looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <h3>Department</h3>
    <select class="selectpicker">
        <option data-content="<img src='/Content/Images/dept_cargo.png' /> CARGO">
            CARGO</option>
        <option data-content="<img src='/Content/Images/dept_commercial.png' /> COMMJ">
            COMMJ</option>
        <option data-content="<img src='/Content/Images/dept_executive.png' /> EXECJ">
            EXECJ</option>
        <option data-content="<img src='/Content/Images/dept_travel.png' /> TVL">
            TVL</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The dropdown appears as expected, but it doesn't drop down when I click on it.

What have I missed?

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because template was added dynamically, but the code `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();` will only execute once after dom ready.

So you need write a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) by yourself, or use the library [angular-bootstrap-select](https://github.com/joaoneto/angular-bootstrap-select)

Comment: @serlingpa If you are using it, you need import it like [this](https://github.com/joaoneto/angular-bootstrap-select#html-snippet). Then you need require it in your angular module definition like this: `angular.module('app', ['angular-bootstrap-select'])`.

Comment: I'm doing all of those things but it's still not happy.

Comment: @serlingpa Can you post your code to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Then I can check what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Oops. I got it wrong. I am only using bootstrap-select, not angular-bootstrap-select. I will look into angular-bootstrap-select. Thanks!

Comment: Why it is design so? This seems non practical.